# How can I fix my hotspot?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I'm on a Google Pixel XL, stock, unrooted. Android 8.1.0, build OPM1.171019.021
My Carrier is T-Mobile, via Straight talk BYOP program.

I was able to hotspot (WiFi tethering) without any trouble at all. Then one day my computer lost connection to my hotspot, so I checked my phone, and it was off. Turning it back on, I had a notification that said "Your phone shut off due to heat." It didn't feel hot at the time, compared to other times that I've used it and it felt warm to the touch. Since then, I'm unable to connect through tethering.

Built in WiFi Hotspot and USB tether give the same problem.

A few things I've found: 
When connection another phone, it authenticates, then says "Connected, No Internet" 
On a Linux machine, when I ping google.com it can resolve Google's IP address, but has 100% packet loss. 
On a Mac, PDANet app allowed me to get online, though I need to be able to WiFi hotspot without PDANet.
When using a WiFi file transfer app, I'm able to connect to the hotspot and transfer files to/from the phone without any problems.

A few things I've tried:
-Reboot phone 
-Contact Carrier to check/reset data settings on their end 
-Reset APN settings 
-Factory reset phone 
-Replace SIM card

What can I do to get this fixed? It was fine for a long time, then suddenly, this happens and nothing seems to fix it.

Also, the SE websites confuse me, so I have no idea which one to ask this on. I've asked Android specific questions on Android SE and was closed for being off topic. If possible, please just tell me where to ask or migrate my question instead of flagging it. I don't know where to ask about this sort of thing, and I prefer the SE community over other Q&A sites where I can only get the opinion of trolls. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but I actually run on pure Linux machines. I realize I was unclear in my question when mentioning a Mac with PDANet. This solution won't work for me, unfortunately.